# Remove online account icons from Ubuntu dock

Tags: icons, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, online-accounts

I have connected two Google accounts to my Ubuntu 19.10 PC to access easily to the documents stored in Google Drive. Ubuntu has added the accounts to '*Files*' shortcuts, which is how I "mount" GDrive:
[image]

But it also added two icons to the dock, which are completely useless, since I can use them only to mount the "drives" and still have to access them through the *Files* app. A left click on the icons does nothing and with right click I get a menu with four entries of which only the first two work:
[image]

How can I remove those useless icons from the dock?